# Shape dataset for classification

Tags: data-request

For a project, I need a shape (circle, square,triangle, cylinder, rectangle) dataset and I want to use this dataset for image classification.
The images can have width and height in the range 256.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Need more specific ? Are you doing this to do GIS or Remote Sensing work ?

Comment: Well, I want to do some experiment for image similarity. @PROBERT

Comment: Still unclear to me.

Comment: I want to use siamese network for image similarity. And I am interested to use shape dataset. For example, a circle is different from a square. @PROBERT